# How to find values in column that have no full stops in table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to find the values in a column that do not have any full stops.

Input:

```
COK0105.D.SKE 
WAL1101
No value found
WAL1802.C    
STR0001
```

Output:

```
STR0001
WAL1101
```

I have 40K records in the table and I can't keep looking for them manually.

Comment: You have not provided what you have tried out for this

Comment: select * from mytable where colum_1!='%.%'

Comment: for matching string LIKE keyword should be used

Comment: Simply `...where column not like '%.%'`.

Comment: @Looking_for_answers your query  
select * from mytable where colum_1!='%.%' will not work, you have to use  NOT LIKE operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT LIKE ('%.%');
```

it will fetch all the rows which does not contain "." anywhere in the text

Comment: Thank you. its exactly what  i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from mytab where mycol not like '℅[ .]%'
```

Comment: According to your example `No value found` should be filter out